# Easy way to generate document with several independent (and separated) set of publications

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I'm making my resume and I'd like to add my list of publications. However, I have a different `.bib` file for each kind of publication (since I am trying to add book chapters separated from international publications, separated from congress appearances, etc). Each one of the `bib` files has  its own section for them to go to in the main CV file.

The way I have been doing this is by creating a separate small script for each `bib`, such as this one below (there are 4 more like this)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{myintpubs}
\end{document}
```

Which generates a pdf document, but also generates a `.bbl` file. So I manually compile each of these little scripts (one for each kind of publication I'm trying to separate) and input the generated `.bbl` files in their own section at the main pdf. Like this:

```
\begin{rSection}{International Journal Publications}
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\input{./makerefen2/intpub_makeref.bbl}
\endgroup
\end{rSection}

{\bf Talks and presentations}\\
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\input{./makerefen/talk_makeref.bbl}
\endgroup
```

And then I compile the main pdf and everything works out. The problem is that this is very inefficient, given that for every change I make I have to do `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex` just to generate the `.bbl`s (for each of the `bib` files), and only then compile the main pdf.

I'm pretty sure there's a better way to do this. Perhaps using `biblatex` instead of `bibtex`. So my question is: what's a cleaner, better way of doing this?

PS: this is related to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160300/how-can-i-make-a-curriculum-vitae-or-resume-in-tex-with-variable-length) question (and I believe the answer to that also applies here), but I simply could not reproduce that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `biblatex` and biber you don't have to go through the ordeal of using different `.bib` files. It is very easy to filter bibliography lists by publication type (entry type).

You could just do

```
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles in peer-review journals}]
\printbibliography[type=book,title={Books}]
\printbibliography[nottype=book,nottype=article,title={Other stuff I did}]
```

and would be done with it.

Note that you can not only filter bibliographies by `type`, you can also use `keywords` in your `.bib` file and categories on the fly from the document itself as well as other more intricate filtering with bibfilters.

You can still use this approach, if you want. Just load all `.bib` files with `\addbibresource`.

See also [Sectioning bibliography by type of referred item](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20246/35864).

---

But you can also use a method that relies on the separation by `.bib` file only. (This is especially useful if you need more fine-grained separation than just by entry types and already have the `.bib` files set up for this task.)

For that we assign a `label` to each `.bib` file when we load it with `\addbibresource`:

```
\addbibresource[label=books]{mybib-books.bib} 
\addbibresource[label=articles]{mybib-articles.bib}
```

We then use `refsection`s to separate the bibliographies, each refsection gets one of the `.bib` files identified via its label.

```
\begin{refsection}[books]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Books}]
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}[articles]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Articles}]
\end{refsection}
```

Will print two bibliographies. The first coming from `mybib-books.bib` (identified with the `books` label) and the second from `mybib-articles.bib` (identified with `articles`).

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-books.bib}
@book{book1,
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  title = {My First Book},
  date = {2010},
}
@book{book2,
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  title = {My Second Book},
  date = {2010},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-articles.bib}
@article{article1,
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  title = {My First Article},
  journal = {Best Journal Ever},
  date = {2012},
}
@book{article2,
  author = {Anne Uthor},
  title = {My Second Article},
  journal = {Journal of Articles},
  date = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource[label=books]{\jobname-books.bib} 
\addbibresource[label=articles]{\jobname-articles.bib} 

\begin{document}
\begin{refsection}[books]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Books}]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}[articles]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title={Articles}]
\end{refsection}
\end{document}
```