# Object/class-like system for CV items?

Tags: bibtex, cv

Bibtex & friends provide a great way to keep all the info for a citation (authors, title, etc.) in a data file so you can display it in whatever format you need using functions from whatever your favorite bibliography package is. This approach seems really useful for a CV in general: some sort of structured text file or latex "object" to store the actual information (job title, dates, bullet points for description), and then a package or class containing functions to turn that into formatted output depending on what you need from each CV instance.

Is there a way to create data structures like this in LaTeX?

Comment: You can use `biblatex` to manage a bibtex like database for informaiton related to a cv, see the following answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79384/16895

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: I use biber/biblatex to do this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160300/how-can-i-make-a-curriculum-vitae-or-resume-in-tex-with-variable-length/160309#160309

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/bausteineBewerbung/tree/databaseapproach